# Could you please provide sample NFT marketplace smart contract(s) to be compatible with ERC1155, to create multiple NFT's at a time..?

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin, erc-1155

Looking for a sample marketplace smart contract and ERC1155 NFT smart contract to create multiple NFT's at a time, from the marketplace. Preferably that contract should import from openzapplin. I am **not looking** for an ERC721 compatible contract.

you can provide any GitHub repo or doc or any resource which you had.

Comment: Here is a demo project. But it's 15 month's old. https://github.com/matprime/ERC-1155-NFT-demo

Comment: This might help you as well: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-erc1155/tree/master/contracts